# When will a human see Allah?

Tags: allah

Is it right after we die in soul form? Do we see the angels in soul form or no?
Or only on the Day of Judgment?
Or only if we enter paradise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Do you overlook a crowd to see the full moon? Do you overlook a crowd to see the sun?” They said no. The Prophet said, “Verily, you will see your Lord just as you see the full moon and you will not need to overlook a crowd to see him.”

Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2554

The Prophet (ﷺ) said: INNALLAHA JAMILUN YUHIBBUL JAMAL – “Allah is beautiful and He loves beauty.” [Muslim]

So nothing will be more joyful than Looking at your creator who is the most powerful, beautiful, merciful.

At judgement day, our body and soul will be combined so we can enjoy the reward or punishment of our doings in this world. Body is required so we can feel the pain in hell or enjoy the blessing of paradise.

Angels will treat us according to our result. If we will pass then they will respectfully take us towards paradise. If not then they will grab a person from his jaw and push him with force and take him to hell with humiliation.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that the inhabitants of Jannah will be allowed to see Allah's face.

May Allah make us among them.

Allah Knows best

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to see the Angels even in this world, but nobody are able to see Allah.

> «و لا یحیطون به علما؛». (طه / ۱۱۰)

If you look at somebody, it means that you are able to access his/her body, so with respect to this fact, you are able to see something that has a physical body, Allah doesn't have a physical body. 
But you can see Allah by looking at its signs in this material world as what the Quran said.